# Short story where statues have their heads replaced by those of carved insect heads

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story that takes place after the apocalypse/societal breakdown? Can’t remember much else about it except for the final scene. The protagonists find that the statues in the park/square? have had their heads removed and replaced with the carved heads of insects. I think they are being pursued as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is Alfred Bester's "[They Don't Make Life Like They Used To](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40874)"

> ...directed her gaze at the Wonderland monument...
>
> A consummate craftsman had removed the heads of Alice, the Mad
> Hatter, and the March Hare, and replaced them with towering mantis
> heads, all saber mandibles, antenna, and faceted eyes.

The story takes place in New York City, and the reference is to the famous Alice In Wonderland monument in Central Park.

[image]
(photo from [centralpark.com](https://www.centralpark.com/))

Comment: Just curious why you switched to this as the dup target; both this question and definitely this answer have less detail than the one you closed.

Comment: @DavidW just because it's older. If you want to change it back, I won't edit-war it. And congrats on your gold badge!

Answer (score 3):

Possibly Missile Gap by Charles Stross (available [online](https://subterraneanpress.com/magazine/spring_2007/fiction_missile_gap_by_charles_stross/)). A Rushmore-style monument gets an insect head.

Comment: "Rushmore-style" is correct. That was the Soviet counterpart of Mount Rushmore, with Stalin, Lenin and Marx on display. And ... something ... else. And all the comrades are dead. "You know Yuri, I think we have found the communist brothers from the stars. And something tells me we didn't want to."